# Rust ink! Utc::now() from chrono libary returns : function or associated item not found in `chrono::Utc'

Tags: ink, rust, smart-contract, timestamp

as the title suggests.
I imported chrono 0.4 just like in the documentation [Here](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.0/chrono/index.html)

And when i ever i call Utc::now() to get current UTC time, i get error that the function now() doesn't not exists.

Here is my Cargo import:

```
chrono =  { version = "0.4", default-features = false}
```

Here is the code snippet to get current UTC time:

```
        use chrono::prelude::*;

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get_todays_date(&self) ->  String{
            //let local= Local::now();
            let utc= Utc::now();
            utc.to_string()
        }
```

When i ever i try to compile this code, i get the following error:

```
    |
335 |             let utc= Utc::now();
    |                           ^^^ function or associated item not found in `chrono::Utc`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can't use `chrono::Utc::now` in WASM=) Because it requires `std` to get the local time of the machine. If you want to get the current time then you need to get the timestamp of the block `ink_env::block_timestamp`. After you can convert it into `Date` or `Utc` and so on.